# How are Google Protocol repeated values structured? What are their limitations and advantages?

Tags: java, c++, protocols, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to create an array that is going to transfer data from C++ application to a Java app. Because of the two languages, how do you format the a Google Protocol message?

Also, what are their limitations and advantages?

So far, I have the following:

```
message Config {
    repeated string types = 1;
}
```

I think I'm missing somethings!

Comment: Do you mean "how is this structured on the wire?" - or do you mean "how do I work with this in my app?" - they're very different questions.

Comment: I mean, "how is this structured on the wire?"

Comment: the encoding spec is available - just search "protobuf encoding" - however, frankly that's only of interest to library implementors. If you're just consuming an existing library, it is the job of the library to worry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean *on the wire* - then firstly: it is the serializer's job to worry about that, but *in this case* it is implemented simply as (per repeated element):

```
0x0a = "field 1, length prefixed" (strings are always length prefixed)
{number of bytes as UTF8, varint-encoded}
{that many bytes of UTF8}
```

So if you have 3 items repeated you'll have 3 lots of 0x0a, varint, payload slammed one after the other. In the case of some primitive types - integers etc, there is a "packed" encoding that removes the need for a header per element, by prepending the byte-length of the entire array *first*, then just the array contents as raw non-tokenized data.

---

If you mean *from the caller's perspective*, then: it is down to the implementation, but essentially you should expect *some familiar API* - common to that framework. This might mean that `repeated` data is exposed as an array / vector, or it might mean a "collection" class with an `Add` etc API. It will depend entirely on what is sensible for the target framework and the implementing author's whimsy.